# Is old affdex-sdk still available to use for academic purposes for free?

Tags: affdex-sdk

It looks like affdex-sdk has been integrated into iMotion platform. However, my works are still based on the old affdex-sdk that I have downloaded.

So my question is whether I can still publish those results or it must require a license from iMotion?

Thanks

Hare

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.affectiva.com/what/products/

> Affectiva is no longer making it’s SDK and Emotion as a Service
> offerings directly available to new developers. Academic researchers
> should contact iMotions, who have our technology integrated into their
> platform.